# React confirm alert handle key press = enter

Tags: reactjs

```
import { confirmAlert } from "react-confirm-alert"; // Import
import "react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css"; // Import css

export default function App() {
  const handleButtonPress = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      alert("Click Yes");
    }
  };

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    confirmAlert({
      title: "Confirm to submit",
      message: "Are you sure to do this.",
      buttons: [
        {
          label: "Yes",
          onClick: () => {
            alert("Click Yes");
          },
          onKeyPress: () => {
            handleButtonPress();
          }
        },
        {
          label: "No",
          onClick: () => {
            alert("Click No");
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          handleClick();
        }}
      >
        Click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm testing **react-confirm-alert**.

I'm trying to handle Button Yes by pressing Enter. Both function **onClick()** for **yes** and **no** are working good, but **press enter** is not working.

Can someone let me know if I did something wrong?

Comment: Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them. The error in the console will clearly tell you what's going on.

Comment: I got a message anytime I pressed enter. "Warning: You are calling ReactDOMClient.createRoot() on a container that has already been passed to createRoot() before. Instead, call root.render() on the existing root instead if you want to update it."

Answer (score 0):

There's several issues. This `react-confirm-alert` library looks like a poor library, I'd pick a different one if you can find one that suits your needs.

You're calling `handleButtonPress()` with no arguments, and then you're trying to read from the `event` object, which you don't pass.

```
  const handleButtonPress = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
```

The `event.key` line should be throwing an error since `event` is undefined. Since you're not seeing errors, it's clear this line isn't getting called. You should be using `console.log` or the debugger to double check what code is getting called.

You should also get in the habit of reading documentation. In this case, [the documentation](https://github.com/GA-MO/react-confirm-alert/#options) shows that `onKeyPress` is a top level setting, while you've incorrectly put it in `buttons`.

Either way, `react-confirm-alert` doesn't pass the event to the `onKeyPress` callback: https://github.com/GA-MO/react-confirm-alert/#options so it doesn't seem like this API should exist. It doesn't have any use.

I would either pick a different library, otherwise you'll need to add your own keypress listener to the document, and manually handle the enter key there.